# iMessages - same message on two devices

Tags: messages, privacy

I once bought a macbook for my friend. I logged into it using my own apple account to make sure it worked properly before delivering it to him. However, he now gets a copy of my iMessages. How can this link be removed so he will no longer be able to see my messages?

Comment: Did you log out? Did you use forget this device in your Account.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences→iCloud on his machine, sign out of your iCloud account and into his.